# Return `false` when press and `true` when press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button and when it is clicked it needs to disable the keyCodes `49,50,51,52,53,54`.

And when I click keyCode `27` it needs to return `true` for all the keyCodes.

```
button_size_1.onclick = function() {
  $("html").bind("keydown", function(e) {
    if (
      e.keyCode == 49 ||
      e.keyCode == 50 ||
      e.keyCode == 51 ||
      e.keyCode == 52 ||
      e.keyCode == 53 ||
      e.keyCode == 54
    ) {
      return false;
      console.log("false");
    } else if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      return true;
      console.log("true");
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a variable which tells if keyCode 27 has been pressed or not. Take a look at the example below. The `keyCode27Pressed` value resets every time the button gets clicked. It will be changed to true once the key with keyCode 27 has been pressed and after that it will return true for all defined keys pressed.

```
button_size_1.onclick = function() {
  let keyCode27Pressed = false;
  $("html").bind("keydown", function(e) {
    if (
      e.keyCode == 49 ||
      e.keyCode == 50 ||
      e.keyCode == 51 ||
      e.keyCode == 52 ||
      e.keyCode == 53 ||
      e.keyCode == 54
    ) {
      if (!keyCode27Pressed) {
          console.log("false");
          return false;
      } else {
          console.log("true");
          return true;
      }
    } else if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      keyCode27Pressed = true;
      console.log("true");
      return true;
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're writing `console.log()` AFTER the return, which will never work as it doesn't read any code that comes afterwards. You need to put the `console.log()` first :

```
if (e.keyCode == 49 || e.keyCode == 50 || e.keyCode == 51 || e.keyCode == 52 || e.keyCode == 53 || e.keyCode == 54) {
  console.log("false");
  return false;
} else if (e.keyCode == 27) {
  console.log("true");
  return true;
}
```

So it does return true, it just didn't show you anything in the console cuz of this simple problem :-)

Comment: Okay that works for the console but when i press keycode 27 it need to return also true for the keycodes 49,50,51,52,53,54 but they are still not working

Comment: @YouSeeStefan if it needs to return true for the keycode 27 and everything else, why don't you write in the first if `... || e.keyCode == 27` and return true? I don't understand what the problem is in that case.

Comment: He wants enable [keys that return true] when 27 is pressed and disable them when his button is pressed. Simple toggle but question not written very well.

Comment: Yeah that's what i want sorry for the question is not written very well